# taking the limit of $f(x)$, questions

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I take the limit of the following functions?

I had included some of my thoughts with them.

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{4x^3 - 2x + 1}{8x^3 + \sin(x^2) - x^{-1}}$; my thoughts: I am not sure about the bottom since there are the sine function and $-1$ power

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{x^{x-1}}$; my thoughts: isn't $e^x$ faster since $x^{x-1}$ is one power lower than the top?

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x^x}{x^{x+1}}$; my thoughts: the bottom is faster since is one power higher than the top.

Ty!

Comment: Try L'Hopital rule.

Comment: For the first one, you take the greatest degree in the numerator and denom to obtain $\frac{1}{2}$; for the 2nd, use $x^a=e^{a\ln x}$. The 3rd one is trivial $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Is this the first course in calaculus?

Comment: @DannyCheuk L'Hopital's works any time evaluating the integral results in $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$.

Comment: Messed up, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @DannyCheuk I did too lol, I meant to say "limit", but I think you got the idea :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first one

$$ \dfrac{4x^3 - 2x + 1}{8x^3 + \sin(x^2) - x^{-1}}=\dfrac{4x^4 - 2x^2 + x}{8x^4 + x\sin(x^2) - 1}\sim_{\infty} \dfrac{4x^4 }{8x^4 } = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Added:** Recalling Stirling approximation

> $$ n!=\Gamma(n+1) \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2 \pi n}, $$

we have

$$ \frac{e^x}{x^{x-1}}= \frac{x}{x^{x}e^{-x}}\sim_{\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{x}\Gamma(x+1) }=0. $$

Can you do the other one?

**Note:** Another approach to do the last two limits is to use the result

> If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = a$ and $|a|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n} =0. $

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to consider:

1. What does $x^{-1}$ tend to at infinity? How big is $\sin$ compared to a polynomial at infinity?
2. Have you tried making everything in terms of $e^x$? What happens when $x$ is larger than $e$... larger than $e^2$, $e^3$?
3. *Hint:* $x^{x+1} = x^x\cdot x$

Answer (score 1):

In your first limit, lower powers of $x$ become small by comparison to higher powers as $x\to\infty$, and $x^{-1}\to0$.  And $\sin(x)$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$, so it becomes negligible by comparison to things like $x^3$, that go to $\infty$.

And "become small" and "becomes negligible" actually means they approach $0$ by comparison, i.e. their ratio to $x^3$ approaches $0$.

Hence you have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{4x^3 + \text{something negligible}}{8x^3 + \text{something negligible}}.
$$