# Why is this limit $\frac{e^x}{x^{x-1}}$coming out wrong?

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function

Attempting to answer this question, I thought to evaluate the limit by taking the logarithm and then using L'Hopital's rule:

$$\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{x^{x-1}}\\
\ln{L}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{(x-1)\ln(x)} \\
\ln{L}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{(x-1)\frac{1}{x}+\ln{x}} \\
\ln{L}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}+\ln{x}} \\
\ln{L}&=0 \\
e^{\ln{L}} &=e^0 \\
L&=1
\end{align}$$

But [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e5uc37b0k47) says that the limit is $0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $\ln(a/b)\ne \ln a/\ln b$.

Comment: See here for the [techniques](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451924/taking-the-limit-of-fx-questions/451930#451930).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\ln(e^x/x^{x-1}) =x-(x-1)\ln x\neq \frac{x}{(x-1)\ln x}$$